RAID 5 failure after multiple drives got disconnected
I've been running a linux software RAID 5 undergoing a reshape(4→6 devices) and multiple drives got disconnected unexpectedly. The drives themselves are perfectly fine but the RAID array is in a state that mdadm can't rectify on its own and I don't know how to go about recovering this. I didn't try any potentially destructive recovery techniques and it is unlikely(although not entirely ruled out) that the array was written to when this happened, chances are the filesystem on it wasn't even mounted, so I have high hopes to recover this given the right pointers :)
(before you ask, yes I'm a big dumb-dumb and don't have backups)
# uname -a
Linux Cyberdyne-Debian 6.1.0-25-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.106-3 (2024-08-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux
# mdadm --version
mdadm - v4.2 - 2021-12-30 - Debian 4.2-5

mdadm --examine for all involved devices:
/dev/sda1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x45
     Array UUID : 35ecd13e:77bd06bd:de30f190:6b7f03b8
           Name : Cyberdyne-Debian:1  (local to host Cyberdyne-Debian)
  Creation Time : Tue Sep 17 22:47:41 2024
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 3906762752 sectors (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 9766737920 KiB (9.10 TiB 10.00 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906695168 sectors (1862.86 GiB 2000.23 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
     New Offset : 259072 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 6dd3585e:6db7833e:96bd1cdb:5a0519f4

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 1341967360 (1279.80 GiB 1374.17 GB)
  Delta Devices : 2 (4->6)

    Update Time : Tue Sep 24 10:02:41 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 41297aaf - correct
         Events : 66589

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 5
   Array State : A.A.AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x45
     Array UUID : 35ecd13e:77bd06bd:de30f190:6b7f03b8
           Name : Cyberdyne-Debian:1  (local to host Cyberdyne-Debian)
  Creation Time : Tue Sep 17 22:47:41 2024
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 3906762752 sectors (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 9766737920 KiB (9.10 TiB 10.00 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906695168 sectors (1862.86 GiB 2000.23 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
     New Offset : 259072 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 72f87daa:888164f8:dfc7f0cf:31ee54cd

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 1341967360 (1279.80 GiB 1374.17 GB)
  Delta Devices : 2 (4->6)

    Update Time : Tue Sep 24 10:02:41 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 153f5ceb - correct
         Events : 66589

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : A.A.AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x45
     Array UUID : 35ecd13e:77bd06bd:de30f190:6b7f03b8
           Name : Cyberdyne-Debian:1  (local to host Cyberdyne-Debian)
  Creation Time : Tue Sep 17 22:47:41 2024
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 3906762752 sectors (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 9766737920 KiB (9.10 TiB 10.00 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906695168 sectors (1862.86 GiB 2000.23 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
     New Offset : 259072 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 34816406:8ac2790b:9cdd3d47:13e87a09

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 1341967360 (1279.80 GiB 1374.17 GB)
  Delta Devices : 2 (4->6)

    Update Time : Tue Sep 24 10:02:41 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 37ae3651 - correct
         Events : 66589

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 4
   Array State : A.A.AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sde1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x45
     Array UUID : 35ecd13e:77bd06bd:de30f190:6b7f03b8
           Name : Cyberdyne-Debian:1  (local to host Cyberdyne-Debian)
  Creation Time : Tue Sep 17 22:47:41 2024
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 3906695168 sectors (1862.86 GiB 2000.23 GB)
     Array Size : 9766737920 KiB (9.10 TiB 10.00 TB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
     New Offset : 259072 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 2f6b8a7e:0b60a5fc:04649248:dd5a054e

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 1341967360 (1279.80 GiB 1374.17 GB)
  Delta Devices : 2 (4->6)

    Update Time : Tue Sep 24 10:02:41 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : e6ddaefc - correct
         Events : 66589

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : A.A.AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdf1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x45
     Array UUID : 35ecd13e:77bd06bd:de30f190:6b7f03b8
           Name : Cyberdyne-Debian:1  (local to host Cyberdyne-Debian)
  Creation Time : Tue Sep 17 22:47:41 2024
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 3906762752 sectors (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 9766737920 KiB (9.10 TiB 10.00 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906695168 sectors (1862.86 GiB 2000.23 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
     New Offset : 259072 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 06fac7a7:849c3cb6:b07bb763:077bf0a1

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 1341975040 (1279.81 GiB 1374.18 GB)
  Delta Devices : 2 (4->6)

    Update Time : Tue Sep 24 10:01:39 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 38c5f5ec - correct
         Events : 66590

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdg1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x45
     Array UUID : 35ecd13e:77bd06bd:de30f190:6b7f03b8
           Name : Cyberdyne-Debian:1  (local to host Cyberdyne-Debian)
  Creation Time : Tue Sep 17 22:47:41 2024
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 3906762752 sectors (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 9766737920 KiB (9.10 TiB 10.00 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906695168 sectors (1862.86 GiB 2000.23 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
     New Offset : 259072 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 5b7b7ef7:7329c7b5:1aa7aad3:3d1188e5

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 1341975040 (1279.81 GiB 1374.18 GB)
  Delta Devices : 2 (4->6)

    Update Time : Tue Sep 24 10:01:39 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 3b91c5ce - correct
         Events : 66590

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)


I figured out a solution by now. First I created overlays for the RAID members like described here, but I did it TWICE for each raid member. On each set of overlay-ed members I ran mdadm --create --assume-clean. One with only the initial 4 members and the parameters before the reshape and the other with all 6 members and post-reshape parameters(taking the new data offset into account).
At this point I have one array where the beginning of the original array is intact but the end is corrupted(the post-reshape one) and another array where the beginning is corrupted but the end is intact(the pre-reshape one), so I need to stitch together both arrays at the cross-over point, which can be done with dmsetup.
Since there is plenty of valid pre-reshape data that has been copied to the new reshaped structure and also hasn't been overwritten yet, I can safely subtract a substantial number of sectors from the reported reshape position to avoid any potential weirdness at the edge of the reshaped data, just to be safe.
Took some time and effort but it worked.
